# Should I break code escapes for non-code suffixes?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

Sometimes I need to add a suffix to a *word* of code to make it fit with the sentence, and I'm not sure whether I ought to add the suffix inside the escape, or end the escape and tack it on to the end.

Consider the keyword `blit` in the unformatted sentence *"Have you tried blitting it?"*

Supposing that the natural solution, *"Have you tried using `blit`?"* isn't an option for some good reason, is the better format *"Have you tried `blitting` it?"*, or is *"Have you tried `blit`ting it?"* more appropriate?

In the former case, the code will not run since there is no expression `blitting`, but in the latter case, the sentence is 'ugly' and somewhat more difficult to read. It comes up even more frequently for pluralized expressions, like *"How many `update`s have you called?"* or *"Add more `rect`s!"* and suchthelike.

So far, I've been trying to rephrase my sentences to accommodate both grammar and literal correctness, but sometimes it just doesn't work out. Is there a correct format? Or is it up to each user's discretion?

This question is specific only to small code escapes, rather than multiline code blocks. It mainly affects detailed explanations and comments.

Comment: Why not: *Have you tried using `blit`?*

Comment: Either rephrase the sentence, e.g. "try using `blit`"; or don't use any code formatting ("try blitting it"). In general, use code formatting for things that are definitely code, e.g. a class or function name, and refrain from using it in other cases.

Comment: Generally, I try and set up the sentence to avoid the problem, but it doesn't always go that way. I feel like unformatted sentences are probably the way to go where it's inescapable.

Comment: I would opt for the solution where you don't have to make up words that do not exist. If you really have to I would use a hyphen (-) or apostrophe (') to concatenate things together.

Comment: Especially in comments, inline-`<code>`s are no problem for me.

Comment: Rather than present progressive, you could just put it in infinitive like so: "Have you tried to `blit` it?"

Comment: You could just use: _Have tried to `blit`?_ _blitting_ doesn't sound right, even if it is.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I personally assume that things formatted as code, both inline and as blocks, are to be intended *literally*. In fact I avoid even unwanted pluralizations inside code formatting.

So, if you really **have** to use that kind of word either avoid using the code formatting, as in *Have you tried "blitting" it?*, or put it only in the meaningful portion of the text, as in *Have you tried `blit`ing it?*.

This last option does look a bit ugly, however it has the advantage of showing clearly which is the part of the name that the OP should search for.

Comment: Agreed about literalness.  To this end, i'll even prefer messed-up grammar over code formatting that isn't literal.  "If you `break`ed here, for example..."

Comment: @cHao: It's much better than `brok`en code, yeah :-)